# Why replacing '%20 ' fails in bookmarlet?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

If I run this code in a JS fiddle, everything works as expected :

```
let s = '%s';
let a = 'a%20b';
let b = 'a b';
a = a.replace(/%20/g, ' ');
alert(a);
b = encodeURIComponent(b);
b = b.replace(/%20/g, ' ');
alert(b);
```

It returns `a b` `a b`

But if I run the same in a bookmarlet :

`javascript: let s = '%s'; let a = 'a%20b'; let b = 'a b'; a = a.replace(/%20/g, ' '); alert(a); b = encodeURIComponent(b); b = b.replace(/%20/g,' '); alert(b);`

It returns `a b` `a%20b`, while I would expect `a b` `a b`

What is going wrong here ?

Comment: A bookmarklet is essentially a URL. In URLs, `%20` is a space, so you need to encode the `%` signs as `%25`. Consider using a userscript manager instead.

Comment: I guess I’ll write an answer. The closest thing to a duplicate target I could find was [Safari 5 changes on use of javascript bookmarklets?](/q/7324022/4642212), but that doesn’t really fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bookmarklets](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) come in the form of `javascript:` URLs and are, as the name suggests, URLs.<sup>1</sup>
This means that the usual rules of [URL encoding](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/percent-encoding) and [special characters restrictions](//datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3) apply.

Let’s consider your bookmarklet: `javascript: let s = '%s'; let a = 'a%20b'; let b = 'a b'; a = a.replace(/%20/g, ' '); alert(a); b = encodeURIComponent(b); b = b.replace(/%20/g,' '); alert(b);`.

When the bookmarklet is executed, it’s parsed as a URL and the `javascript:` scheme is stripped.
During parsing, the script is decoded:

- `%s'` is not a valid percent-encoding sequence.
- `%20` is the encoding for a   (space).

[`decodeURI`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) will throw a *“`URIError`: malformed URI sequence”*.
Very likely, [Safari won’t execute this script](/q/7324022/4642212).
Firefox and Chrome seem to ignore the invalid encoding sequence and treat it as a plain `%`.
That’s quite unsafe, because a valid sequence *would* — perhaps unexpectedly — be correctly decoded.

But everything else is the same: the resulting script is this: `let s = '%s'; let a = 'a b'; let b = 'a b'; a = a.replace(/ /g, ' '); alert(a); b = encodeURIComponent(b); b = b.replace(/ /g,' '); alert(b);`.
Note how there is no literal `%20` in your script anymore.

Since you *need* the `%20` literally, you have to *encode* the script as a URL first:

```js
const script = `let s = '%s';
let a = 'a%20b';
let b = 'a b';
a = a.replace(/%20/g, ' ');
alert(a);
b = encodeURIComponent(b);
b = b.replace(/%20/g, ' ');
alert(b);`;

console.log(encodeURI(`javascript:${script}`));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
.as-console-row-code { word-break: break-all; }
```

[`encodeURI`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) will encode your script in a way that is guaranteed to work as a bookmarklet, and, in particular, encodes `%` as `%25`, although it encodes a few special characters perhaps unnecessarily, e.g. `"`, `` ` ``, `[`, `]`, `{`, `}`, `<`, `>`, `\`, `|`, spaces, line breaks.
I don’t actually know how *all* browsers deal with these special characters in bookmarklets, so it’s probably safest to trust this output and use this as your bookmarklet URL:

`javascript:let%20s%20=%20'%25s';%0Alet%20a%20=%20'a%2520b';%0Alet%20b%20=%20'a%20b';%0Aa%20=%20a.replace(/%2520/g,%20'%20');%0Aalert(a);%0Ab%20=%20encodeURIComponent(b);%0Ab%20=%20b.replace(/%2520/g,%20'%20');%0Aalert(b);`

---

But please consider using a [userscript manager](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript_manager) instead.
Bookmarklets are cumbersome and they don’t work on sites that block them using Content Security Policy (CSP) rules.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Could’ve jokingly written *“not URLs”* at the end, because technically they’re not Uniform Resource Locators, because they’re JavaScript code; they don’t locate anything. They’re also neither URIs nor URNs because they’re neither identifiers nor names. The `javascript:` scheme is kind of a hack, because it doesn’t really fit into this taxonomy. They only behave as URLs because the JavaScript code is entered into the URL field of a Bookmark entry.